# Уведомления в определенном радиусе

Tags: java, android

Задача стоит в том что когда один пользователь нажмет на кнопку в андроид приложении например "Отослать уведомление". То его должны получать только те кто в радиусе например 5км неважно какая цифра. Подскажите как это правильно делается. Работаю с Firebase. На данный момент решил эту задача созданием сервиса который всегда активный и слушает ветку в Бд firebase. Когда там появляется что то новое сервис определяет координаты телефона берет координаты с firebase и определяет расстояние. Если оно меньше выводит уведомление. Работает но реализация такая мне не особо нравится. Спасибо заранее если поможете правильно реализовать